# Siri on Custom keyboard App Extension iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, ios-app-extension, siri, custom-keyboard

Currently I am working on a iOS 8 custom keyboard extension and I want to mimic the functionality of Siri similar to the default keyboard.

Can we able to use Siri on iOS 8 Custom keyboard App extension? If we can is there any API/documentation available?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, native Siri access is not yet possible.  You can use something like Nuance ndev to produce this functionality though.  http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com

You should be able to switch back and forth using the globe key so the user will have quick access to the native keyboard in the case they need to dictate.

Answer (score 3):

Custom keyboard is an app extension, so it cannot access to the microphone. And without microphone, we cannot do something like Siri does.

I think we have to wait until Apple changes!

```
Custom keyboards, like all app extensions in iOS 8.0, have no access to the **device microphone**, so dictation input is not possible.
```

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html